# Re-opening a class located in lib folder (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Similar questions have been asked many times. However, I have slightly different scenario and I still to find a clean solution to the following problem while developing a Rails 3 app:

I have a ruby code located in a single file. This code is one module `MyModule` which contains a bunch of classes. I can't modify this code because it's auto-generated by an external tool. The file name is `my_module.rb` and it resides in the `lib` folder. This is the usual place for a code which doesn't belong to the main web app. I made sure it is auto-loaded once I access MyModule in one of my app controllers by modifying `config.autoload_paths` setting in `application.rb`.

Now I need to re-open one of the classes in `MyModule`. I created a separate file `some_class.rb` where I put the following code:

```
    class MyModule::SomeClass
        def some_new_method
           ...
        end
    end
```

My question is: what is the best place to put this code? And what should be the name of the file?

The things I tried:

1. Placing the code into `initializers` folder. it works fine in production environment. However, it breaks in `development` because the code in `initiliazers` folder is loaded once when the server starts up and `lib` is reloaded on each request. So, the first request in development works fine, however, the subsequent requests fail. Also I don't like placing the code into `initializers` because it's not really initialization piece but rather a part of business logic.
2. Placing the code into `lib` folder also doesn't work. It's not loaded. Only `my_module.rb` is.
3. Placing the code into `lib` or some other folder under `app` and then explicitly `requir`ing it in controllers. Again it works in production but fails in development for the same reason aforementioned in case #1.
4. I switched off auto-loading, placed both `my_module.rb` and `some_class.rb` into `lib` folder and `require`ed them in an initializer. I think this is the best approach. The downside is that I still have to create a custom initializer and the code is not loaded lazily.

UPDATE:
5. Thanks to raggi's suggestion, with auto-loading switched on, I put `require_dependency 'some_class'` in my controller. In this case `some_class.rb` is loaded on each request in development mode. This is my preferred approach . However, it still requires some sort of `require` :)

Remember that files in `lib` folder are auto-loaded lazily. Rails checks the folder only when you use modules or classes that rails can't find. The file name must follow the naming convention, hence the name `my_module.rb`.

I wonder if there is a solution when both files are auto-loaded lazily **without** any `require` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try require_dependency in your controller instead of require?

Comment: Just tried. Yes, it works. I guess there is no solution which auto-loads both files lazily without 'require' or 'require_dependency' statement somewhere. The answer to my question would be no, I believe. I up-voted your answer though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the files in the lib directory and have them not lazily loaded but autoloaded, in config/application.rb if you want to put files in different subfolders:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Or if you need only the lib folder:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: That's what I did. I edited my question to mention that. However, the problem is that my_module.rb is autoloaded but some_class.rb is not.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Hide the `require` outside of your mainline code.

I ran in to a similar problem when trying to create a validator within a module during development. I ran across [this blog entry](http://www.nybblr.com/posts/rails-3-auto-require) when I was trying to solve what sounds like the same problem.

```
// Added to application.rb
Rails::Application.config.autoload_paths.each do |d|
  Dir["#{d}/*.rb"].each do |p|
    puts "Requiring '#{p}' on startup..."
    require p
  end
end
```